# How to implement "circular" generator in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Given a generator expression:

```
a = (x for x in range(3)) 
print(next(a)) # 0 
print(next(a)) # 1 
print(next(a)) # 2 
print(next(a)) # StopIteration 
exception 0 1 2 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- StopIteration                             
Traceback (most recent call last) 
<ipython-input-40-863a9b3464a7> in <module>()       
3 print(next(a))       
4 print(next(a)) 
----> 5 print(next(a))  

StopIteration:
```

How can I implement a generator, when the "StopIteration exception" would happen, then it "rewind" to the beginning, returns 0 again?

Comment: What are you trying? How many times should it repeat? Seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: A `cycle` you might say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [itertools.cycle(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) method for this.

It takes an iterable as parameter and cycles through its items.

```
>>>cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D A B C D
```